# Problems to retrieve Image from SQL Server in Silverlight

Tags: sql-server, image, silverlight, store, data-retrieval

I'm kind of new to Silverlight. I've managed to solve this problem for WPF, unfortunately not for Silverlight.

I open an image with an `OpenFileDialog`. I make a stream out of it and write it in a byte array. This byte array is then put into the database. This is the code I use to open the image and convert it into a byte array:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
dlg.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
dlg.FilterIndex = 1;

if(dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
            pImage.Naam = dlg.File.Name;
            BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();

            Stream s = (Stream)dlg.File.OpenRead();
            imgItem.Source = bitImage;

            pImage.Data = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(pImage.Data, 0, (int)s.Length);
            s.Close();
}
```

I manage to save the byte array as a varbinary without any problem to my database.

When I retrieve it, I have no difficulties converting the varbinary back to the byte array (I'm pretty sure the two byte arrays are the same as when debugging I get exactly the same size).

But then I get stuck! Whenever I want to convert the byte array back to an image using the following code, my stream (and thus my image) is empty:

```
var newImage = new BitmapImage();
var myStream = new MemoryStream(pHuidigeImage.Data);
newImage.SetSource(myStream);
imgItem.Source = newImage;
```

So, what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance!